# What are the advantages and disadvantages of extrinsic and perplexity model evaluation in NLP?

Tags: natural-language-processing, comparison, models

In the video [Evaluation and Perplexity](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=b6nwdc_fGfA&list=PLQiyVNMpDLKnZYBTUOlSI9mi9wAErFtFm&index=14) by Dan Jurafsky, the author talks about extrinsic and perplexity evaluation in the context of natural language processing (NLP).

What are the advantages and disadvantages of extrinsic and perplexity model evaluation in NLP? Which evaluation method is preferred usually, and why?

Comment: Maybe [this podcast](https://nlphighlights.allennlp.org/120_evaluation_of_text_generation_with_asli_celikyilmaz) would be helpful.